# Gitlab CI with Flutter and Fastlane Setup Multiple Environments

Tags: flutter, gitlab-ci, fastlane

I'm Building new environment (staging) for my flutter project, on the Dev environment, Gitlab pipeline is working like charm, but when i started working on the staging, I faced a step where i need to replace google play service json/plist file when running the staging CI jobs, so my fastlane upload to store lanes can point to the right project on the stores.

Any idea how i can replace files in the project when working multiple environments using Gitlab CI

Answer (score 1):

You can have your google play service json in the environment variables and depending on build stage add it to the project.

Dont forget to remove your variables.

eg.

```
android-release:
  image: cirrusci/flutter:stable
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - echo ${RELEASE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_JSON} > android/app/google-services.json
  script:
    # build app
  after_script:
   - rm android/app/google-services.json


android-staging:
      image: cirrusci/flutter:stable
      stage: build
      before_script:
        - echo ${STAGING_GOOGLE_SERVICE_JSON} > android/app/google-services.json
      script:
        # build app
      after_script:
       - rm android/app/google-services.json
```

Comment: Worked, but for some reason fastlane upload to store task still trying to push the aab file to the wrong (Dev) project, anything else should be changed ? 

Note, when i upload the aab file manually to the staging project, it get accepted but as mentioned, using fastlane upload to store task, it's pushing to the wring project.

Comment: For this in fastlane point the upload for staging and release to the relevant output of the aabs and you should be fine.

Comment: I changed the package name to be the staging one in the appfile and still it's trying to push the aab file to the wrong project

Comment: please add your yaml

Comment: z:internal:android:deploy_stg:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "Staging"'
  script:
    - cd android
    - bundle exec fastlane deploy_android_stg
  when: manual
  dependencies:
    - android:build_stg
  tags:
    - FLUTTER

Comment: lane :deploy_android_stg do |options|
    upload_to_play_store(
      package_name:'stg package name',
      track: 'internal',
      release_status: 'draft',
      aab: '../build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release-stg.aab',
      skip_upload_images: true,
      skip_upload_screenshots: true,
    )
  end

Comment: your yaml seems alright. Check your credentials